PNPM Installed failed with the Unsupported engineb{ node needed 18 version while package pnpm @9 version}
My node.js package in company computer  cannot  changed the version@16.17.9 npm @8.15.9
How can I install global pnpm with the a whatever  version in my engine?
I was so expected to install this engine with a version can used .
So How can i to do it !!!
when i was remove  pnpm  next to install the engine is failed...

npm rm -g pnpm
npm cache  clean --force
npm install -g pnpm @....
next:  there some notice that:

npm warn ebadengine  Unsupported engine{
npm warn ebadengine package" 'pnpm@9.7.0',
npm warn required:{ node:'>=18.12' },
npm warn current: { node: 'v16.17.0',npm :''8.15.0'}
changed 1 package in 6s
i package is looking fo runding run
for dtails
PS
d :\project\tpbb
git -error  1723079521963
vue
js  git  ts
vite

husky - pre-commit hoook exited with code 127
